# Проблемы с подключение MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Код:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
    
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetools',
                 { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((result) => console.log('connected to db'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Ошибка:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:411:10
    at C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10) 
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1285:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:410:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bymbv\Desktop\clientserv\app.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` — примерно "error: connection refused". перевод требуется?

Comment: Ошибка означает что запрос по адресу был отклонен. Причин может быть много, проверьте адрес, проверьте порт, проверьте работает ли бд в целом

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ, разобрался в проблеме!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что у меня был неправильно настроен localhost.
Поэтому временно использую:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nodetools')
```

Вместо:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetools')
```